# Java ME AudioSamples do not work on Ubuntu

Tags: audio, ubuntu, java-me

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and trying to import Sun Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 audio sample project in NetBeans 6.9. On Windows this works, while on Ubuntu, when running the sample midlet code, it does not make any sound, even not playing a simple tone.

After player.start() nothing happens, checking player.getMediaTime() gets always 0, and finally attempt to stop = player.stop() will not return the call at all.

I've searched all over the place. This post seems to report an answer for a potentially similar problem when using FreeTTs:
[FreeTTS no audio linux ubuntu - no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501394/freetts-no-audio-linux-ubuntu-no-errors)

the suggested workaround involves modifying/replacing the player class in com.sun.speech.freetts.audio packages. I wonder how to find the corresponding class that causes the lock in my case.

Probably it's easier to drop Ubuntu and use Windows VM for development, but at least I'd like to try. Maybe there is a simple solution.

Updated: Any type of player plays well on my Ubuntu box. Also I tried to use different non-me code, such as JLayer or Jorbis based players, even Java sound API. All work. It's just somewhere in the Java ME style player where it breaks down.

Comment: first check with defauly ubuntu player . is it working properly ?

Comment: any type of player plays well on my Ubuntu box. Also I tried to use different non-me code, such as JLayer, Jorbis based player, even Java sound API. All work. It's just somewhere in Java ME style player where it breaks down.